# How can I get a the variable to use in other tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I need `$id` variable to use to populate another table and to use that $id on website. Some reason it is not showing the variable $id.

```
$mysqli=new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query=$this->database->prepare("SELECT master_id FROM builder_newsletter WHERE type='?' AND version='?' AND date='?'");
$query->bind_param("xyz", $type, $version, $date);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($id);
$query->fetch();
printf($id);
$query->close();
```

Comment: Are the types you are giving for the values to bind really "xyz" …?

Comment: no it is not, they are set at sis, which is what they use

Comment: Don't put quotes around placeholders `type='?'`